# How do I select the same date back n amount of years in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date(4/17/2019) and I'd like to compare it to the same date(4/17) back n amount of years(4/17/2018, 4/17/2017, 4/17/2016, etc..). How can I use python to select out a sub group from a dataframe of the date I'm interested in.

Expected output.

```
            PRCP         MAX         MIN
DATE            
2011-04-17  2899.71     49.995000   49.995000
2012-04-17  0.00        0.000000    0.000000
2013-04-17  0.00        0.000000    0.000000
2014-04-17  0.00        0.000000    0.000000
2015-04-17  0.00        0.000000    0.000000
2016-04-17  0.00        0.000000    0.000000
2018-04-17  5799.42     99.990000   99.990000
2019-04-17  5799.42     99.990000   99.990000
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you want to do exactly. What do you want to select exactly? Your title says `n amount of year`. In your question you are talking about a `sub group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strftime`

```
df[df.index.strftime('%m-%d')=='04-17']
```